# Redirect 500 error page to some other page in joomla

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 1.5,I am having some of page with 500.But I want to redirect those page to new page is this possible. below I have given the example.

Old page http://example.com/oldpag [500 eror page]

I want to redirect the above url to new working page

New page http://example.com/newpage

Please advise me..

Regards,
SurezRam

Answer (score 3):

go to folder location: yoursite/template/system/ and modify the error.php, 
put following redirect code after `defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );`

```
header("location: http://example.com/newpage");
exit;
```

Comment: It may be slightly better to copy edit.php to current templates directory, say rhuk_milkyway for example, and insert redirect code there

Answer (score 1):

add the below code to your **.htaccess** file in the root of the  joomla installation if you can't find one create one.

```
# CUSTOM ERROR PAGES
 ErrorDocument 400 URL/error/403.shtml
 ErrorDocument 401 URL/error/403.shtml
 ErrorDocument 403 URL/error/403.shtml
 ErrorDocument 404 URL/error/404.shtml
 ErrorDocument 500 URL/error/500.shtml
# END CUSTOM ERROR PAGES
```

where the url is the url of the site.
I have put respective error files accordingly. for internal server error [500] it would redirect to 500.shtml file inside the error folder. Shtml is nothing but html file with renamed extension.

Comment: I tried this (I just wanted to show the home page, / or /index.php), and it just ended up showing joomla's ugly 'view not found' page instead. I had to put the full URL in the .htaccess file (http://server.com/); that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution in the joomla documentation. This is usable for any error code.

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page

For 1.6 i posted a fix here on this stackoverflow question :

[How do I create a custom error page (404) for Joomla 1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016672/how-do-i-create-a-custom-error-page-404-for-joomla-1-6/5867135#5867135)

This fix would also be necessary for kumarans solution.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for this share , we can also use joomla redirect for more detail you can get it from here

http://webobserve.blogspot.com/2011/03/redirect-error-page-to-some-other-page_09.html